# Bash script fails when putting command into variable

Tags: linux, bash

I try to use ghostscript in a bash script on my linux ubuntu 13.04.

I have a problem to write ghostscript command in variable when the same command written directly, in console or into a script works perfectly.

I don't know how to solve this problem.

Could you help me ?

Example :

My script :

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script PDF_test_ghs.sh

echo "Direct test :"
gs -o PDF_temp_01.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -g7000x5600 -c "<</PageOffset [360 380]>> setpagedevice" -f PDF_initial.pdf

echo ""
echo "Test with variable :"
command='gs -o PDF_temp_02.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -g7000x5600 -c "<</PageOffset [360 380]>> setpagedevice" -f PDF_initial.pdf'
$command
exit 0;
```

and the result is :

```
ubuntu@ubun:~$ PDF_test_ghs.sh 
Direct test :
GPL Ghostscript 9.07 (2013-02-14)
Copyright (C) 2012 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
Processing pages 1 through 3.
Page 1
Page 2
Page 3

Test with variable :
GPL Ghostscript 9.07 (2013-02-14)
Copyright (C) 2012 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
Error: /undefined in "
Operand stack:

Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1167/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:77/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
GPL Ghostscript 9.07: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
ubuntu@ubun:~$
```

The first works and the second does not. I want to use the second. Why does it not work?

Answer (score 0):

Your statement fails because the double quotes inside the command are literal quotes, not syntactical. When you run `$command`, the shell interprets each whitespace-separated part [as an argument](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments), and your

```
"<</PageOffset [360 380]>> setpagedevice"
```

is not "glued" together by the double quotes anymore.

As a simple example, try:

```
command='touch "foo bar"'
$command
```

You'd expect a file called `foo bar` to be created, but instead you get `"foo` and `bar"`. What you could try instead is:

```
eval $command
```

Here, the command would be evaluated as if it were typed in the shell. But don't expect this to work at all times.

---

You should read:
 [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) — storing commands in variables is never recommended. Variables hold data, not commands. If you want to run commands repeatedly, you should use shell functions.

Comment: I'm writing a long script, with many options and the result is this command but i didn't want to make the problem too much complex while answering to be helped.

Comment: You're welcome! Since you're new to Super User, note that you can accept an answer if it helped you by clicking the green checkmark next to it.